# Hibernate buildSessionFactory() not applicable for arguments (ServiceRegistry)

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, compiler-errors

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to create a session manager. Here is the code to create the `SessionFactory` instance:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(config);
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
    configuration.getProperties()
).buildServiceRegistry();

SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
return sessionFactory;
```

When I run this in eclipse, I get the following compile error: `The method buildSessionFactory() in the type Configuration is not applicable for the arguments (ServiceRegistry).`

Using the latest Hibernate version, shouldn't `buildSessionFactory` accept a `ServiceRegistry` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version. You can following line of code to check the version of Hibernate.

```
System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
```

Comment: Turns out I was using version 3.6.10. Must have gotten my .jars confused. Thanks for your help!